# Best practice for inter-server database access through a CMS

Tags: database, postgresql, rest

We are currently running a production server that contains all user data (such as email, hashed passwords, etc), as well as various raw data. The data is delivered there via our mobile app, so there is no web site, but it is REST based.

We now want to create a content management system for some of our customers, so that they can have a nice graphical representation of the raw data. We also want to allow them to edit the data directly.

Having both systems on one server would be the easiest, but ideally we would want to separate these two systems onto different servers. How would this best be done, given that the CMS should be able to access and edit the production server's data without jeopardizing security?

I see several simple solutions but I don't think they're good:

1. Periodically copy all the production data (without passwords) to the CMS server, and create a special REST call on the production server for edits, accepting only connections from the CMS IP.
2. Don't copy any data, but instead make it ALL based on REST calls to the production server, and accept only connections from the CMS IP. This may result in too many calls though.

I should mention that we are currently using sqLite as DB, and as we grow it probably makes sense to switch to a better database such as Postgres. If we were to do that, maybe it would make more sense to connect directly to the DB via tcp/ip when using the CMS? Is that a thing? It's obviously less secure, because anyone getting access to the CMS server could cause great problems, but maybe one can restrict actions to external connections somehow?

I'm sorry if this sounds a bit all over the place, but any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, even though [it sort of works](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62615/how-to-implement-business-logic-permissions-in-postgresql-or-sql-in-general) I wouldn't recommend using an sqlite database for access by multiple users.

Secondly, sqlite lacks [even basic access control features](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) - it just was never designed to do that kind of stuff with.

In my opinion, a more complete SQL server like Postgres would be a way better choice:

- it implements [standard access controls via GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-grant.html)
- you can [create roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createrole.html) to finely tune the rights each user has on all the objects in the database or different databases
- via its [host based authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) you have detailed control on what ways of remote access are allowed, for what users (and hence, with which privileges), eventually enforcing encryption of the data, and from where.

Have a look at[this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62615/how-to-implement-business-logic-permissions-in-postgresql-or-sql-in-general) for a more detailed discussion.

Last but not least, as many people use Postgres servers "in the open] there are many tutorials and information sources on securing a setup properly. Just some examples

- [from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-postgresql-against-automated-attacks)
- [from Bruce Momjian](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/securing.pdf)

There is a learning curve obviously, but it's time well spent and you will end up with a secure and very reliable setup that can handle any load you throw at it if configured properly.